# Filling array with averages

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im wondering about a problem I have in Javascript. I have a scenario where I need to fill gaps in an array with averages of the surrounding values. Let me give an example:

Array:
1, 2, 3, ,4, 5

In this particular case I would need to fill the gap with average of the surrounding numbers, i.e. 3.5. I think this is relatively easy to do.

However, I also need to make sure this works when there is more subsequent gaps in the array.

Example:
1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6

In this case the two gaps should be filled with the average of 3 and 5, resulting in ... 3, 4, 4, 5.

The moment I got stuck was when I tried iterating the array and filling the gaps because I filled the first gap with 4, but at that moment, the surrounding numbers for the second gap were 4 (the original gap) and 5, so I ended up with

... 3, 4, 4.5, 5, ...

which is not what I need.

Im using jQuery to iterate the array and get the values from a table.

This is how Im loading the array:

```
var list = [];
$('#mytable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  list.push(eval($this.find("input.number").val());
}
```

Now I need to iterate and fill the gaps in "list"

Comment: So you have sparse arrays?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Why do you recompute the average after filling the first element in the gap? Just compute the average once for the whole gap, and put that in repeatedly. Then find the next gap.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possible implementation:

```js
function fill(arr) {
  while (arr.includes(undefined)) {
    const startIndex = arr.findIndex(num => num === undefined);
    const endIndex = arr.findIndex((num, i) => i >= startIndex && num !== undefined);
    const avg = (arr[startIndex - 1] + arr[endIndex]) / 2;
    for (let i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) arr[i] = avg;
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(fill([1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6]));
console.log(fill([1, , , , , , 6]));
console.log(fill([1, , , , 3, 4, , , 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using simple iteration.

```js
function fillMissing(arr) {
  // array for storing result
  var res = [];
  // iterate over the array
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // if undefined then call the function to calculate average or set the value
    res[i] = arr[i] == undefined ? calculateAverage(arr, i) : arr[i];
  }
  return res;
}

function calculateAverage(arr1, i) {
  // set preve and next value as nearest element
  var prev = arr1[i - 1],
    next = arr1[i + 1],
    j = 1; // variable for iterating
  
  // iterate to find out nearest defined value
  // after the element
  while (prev == undefined) { prev = arr1[i - ++j]; }
    
  j = 1; //  reset for next iteration
  // iterate to find out nearest defined value
  // before the element
  while (next == undefined) { next = arr1[i + ++j]; }
  
  //find average and return
  return (prev + next) / 2;
}



console.log(fillMissing([1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6]));
console.log(fillMissing([1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6]));
console.log(fillMissing([1, , , , , , 6]));
console.log(fillMissing([1, , , , 3, 4, , , 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
var x = "1, 2, 3, ,4, 5";

var y = "1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6";

var z = "1, , , , , , 6";

var q = "1, , , , 3, 4, , , 6";

function removeSpace(str) {
  return str.replace(/ /g, "");
}

function splitString(str) {
  return str.split(',');
}

function fill(str) {
  var z = removeSpace(str);
  var zPrime = splitString(z);

  for (var i = 0; i < zPrime.length; i++) {
    if (zPrime[i] == "") {
      if (i + 1 < zPrime.length && zPrime[i + 1] != "") {
        zPrime[i] = (Number(zPrime[i - 1]) + Number(zPrime[i + 1])) / 2;
      } else {
        var j = i + 1;
        while (j < zPrime.length && zPrime[j] == "") j++;
        var tp = (j < zPrime.length) ? Number(zPrime[j]) : 0;
        var dn = (i - 1 > -1) ? Number(zPrime[i - 1]) : 0;
        for (var k = i; k < j; k++) {
          zPrime[k] = ((tp + dn) / 2) + '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return zPrime;
}

console.log(fill(x));
console.log(fill(y));
console.log(fill(z));
console.log(fill(q));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the sparse array and store the last index and value. If a gap is found, the gap is filled with the average of the last value and the actual value.

```js
function fill(array) {
  array.reduce((last, v, i, a) => {
      var j, avg;
      if (last.index + 1 !== i) {
          avg = (v + last.value) / 2;
          for (j = 1; j < i - last.index; j++) {
              a[last.index + j] = avg;
          }
      }
      return { index: i, value: v };
  }, { index: -1 });
  return array;
}

console.log(fill([1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6]));
console.log(fill([1, , , , , , 6]));
console.log(fill([1, , , , 3, 4, , , 6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question that made me think a bit.

My first idea was to use `map` but I found that it does not consider holes. Fixed that with `Array.from` that converts holes to `undefined`

I was hoping to find a more concise solution but I'm posting it anyways

```js
function fillMissing(a){
  return Array.from(a).map((e,i)=> e !== undefined ? e : averageAround(i,a))
}

const averageAround = (index, array) => average(before(index, array), after(index, array))
const average = (a, b) => (a+b)/2
const before = findFirstNotUndefined.bind(null, -1)
const after = findFirstNotUndefined.bind(null, 1)

function findFirstNotUndefined(direction, index, array){
  if (array[index] !== undefined) return array[index]
  return findFirstNotUndefined(direction, index+direction, array)
}

console.log(fillMissing([1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6]));
```

Some thoughts:

- recursive call to findFirstNotUndefined is in tail call position
- findFirstNotUndefined should be memoizable, (maybe) useful for large holes
- average around can be written point free style but not without adding another function or importing some fp library like ramda
- Modifying the signature of averageAround like `(_, index, array)`, it can be used directly in the map: `Array.from(a).map(averageAround)`. Cool to read even if it computes the average on every value (`(val + val)/2`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a recursive way to do this, Basically it counts the empty spots between two values and divides the difference over these empty spots:

```
var arr = [1, , , , 3, 4, , , 6];

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    if( arr[ i ] === undefined )
        arr[ i ] = avg( arr[ i - 1 ], arr.slice( i + 1, arr.length ), 1 );
}

function avg( low, arr, recursion ){
    if( arr[ 0 ] === undefined )
        return avg( low, arr.slice( 1, arr.length ), recursion + 1 );

    return low + ( ( arr[0] - low ) / ( recursion + 1 ) );
}

console.log( arr );
```

Works like a charm:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, ,4, 5] => [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5]
arr = [1, 2, 3, , , 5, 6] => [1, 2, 3, 3.6665, 4.3333, 5, 6]
arr = [1, , , , 3, 4, , , 6] => [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.6667, 5.3334, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another functional recursive version

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,,,5,6]

function fill([head,...tail], lastNotNull, holeWidth = 0){
  if (tail.length === 0 ) return head
  if (head === undefined) return fill(tail, lastNotNull, ++holeWidth)
  return Array(holeWidth).fill((lastNotNull+head)/2).concat(head).concat(fill(tail, head))
}

console.log(fill(arr))
```

Explanation:

First parameter of `fill` function is destructured into head and tail. Head represent the current value and tail next values

- Base case: `tail` empty -> we just return `head`
- If current value head is undefined, we recurse increasing the size of the hole and keeping the last not null value, to compute the average
- In all other cases we fill the hole with the average, we add the current value and then recurse onto remaining array, resetting lastNotNull to head and holeWidth to 0 with default value

I feel that the last step could be optimized in terms of execution time but I like the fact that it's compact and clear (if already comfortable with recursion)

Bonus: I love the fact that the hole is filled with the `Array.prototype.fill` function